# Relative links in CSS, after moving Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, relative-path

I created a blog with Wordpress on a temporary test domain.  I put it in the main directory, not a folder.  Now I want to move it to the correct website, in a folder.  I can update all of the MySQL values for the site URL, and the relative path links work just fine.

The problem is that I can't seem to make my CSS path links work.  I realize that my problem is that they are relative to the CSS file, in the WordPress theme, and not the page.  But how can I fix this?

Here is an example:

```
#topNav {background:#3a93c3 url(wp-content/uploads/2011/07/blueNav.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

I have tried adding './', '../', and '../../' to the beginning, but it doesn't work at all.

### Question

Why aren't relative paths working in CSS on my WordPress site?

Comment: what is the absolute path of your CSS file, and of the wp-content directory?

Comment: http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/style.css and http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/

Comment: Is my best/only option to change everything to url(/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/blueNav.jpg)?

Comment: What is the URL to your css file? You should be able to use some combination of `../`

Comment: I think the problem is that it is on a WordPress site.  No combination of ../ does anything.  For example, when I type ../../../ the URL in the CSS turns out to be http://example.com/blog/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/../../../wp-content/uploads/2011/07/blueNav.jpg.  Which, doesn't work obviously.

Comment: Do you have any WP plugins active, that might mangle the CSS? (Like some kind of minifier or so.) Caching plugins? Any of those?

Comment: I'm not sure.  All I installed, since the WordPress install, was the boilerplate theme.  I don't think there are any plugins installed.  I'll see if I can find out.

Comment: No, I do not have any plugins installed, other than the default akismet and hello dolly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you really shouldn't put theme images in the upload folder. you should really store your theme images inside your theme folder. like

```
wp-content/
    themes/
        mytheme/
            images/
                1.jpg
            style.css
```

so in your css, you can just do

```
background:transparent url(images/1.jpg);
```

Comment: I will try this, just for fun, and get back to you in a sec

Comment: Did not work.  It changes the URL to this: h t t p ://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/../images/blueNav.jpg  Notice that it put the ../ into the URL.

Comment: you dont by any chance have a base tag in your template like <base href="http://www.example.com/blog/" />

Comment: oh wait. i think u can just do background:transparent url(images/1.jpg);

Comment: Why would a transparent background help?

Comment: I changed the URL, and it found the image.  Why is it that ../ does not seem to affect the URL?  I mean, when it was in its original folder?

Comment: Funky Dude, I'm giving you the +50 bounty points for merely mentioning base tags.  While it didn't answer the question as to why my URLs weren't working, it made me realize that using base tags are probably ideal, to maintain relative links in templates across directories and domain names.  Thanks :)

Comment: i think that's what i advovated against. you shouldn't use base tag. but as long as it works. ty.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the / which is the root of your website. So something like url(/yourfolder/wp-content/...

If you want to use relative paths, you have to go to the right directory. With the ../ you used before. ../ 1 dir up, add another ../ 2 dir's up, and so on.

Comment: Relative paths will be working in your CSS files, they're rock solid reliable. But you may be using them wrong. Can you edit your question to include more details, such as what the URL is to the css file?

Comment: I think the problem is that it's a WordPress site. I think something is happening when WordPress processes the CSS file.  I can get relative URLs to work in my other sites, just not this one.

Comment: @bozdoz Nopes, WordPress is definitely not responsible. It for one does not "process the CSS file" at all, the stylesheet is included in the `<head>` of the theme as it would be in any ol' website. Also, relative paths can be used in wp.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked my companies corporate blog and I have a couple different ways, there was an old theme that was legacy, and new theme that I made.

First the original base theme used absolute paths:

```
#blogTour {
    background: url('http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/signup.png');
}
```

This generally wasn't ideal since I had to regional-ize blogs, they would have a different URL and I didn't want to use a PHP variables ($SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), maybe you can though!

On the new theme that I made, I put the assets under the theme directory...are you able to put the images within the themes directory?

```
#blogFeed {
    background: url('_images/icons/blog-feed.png');
}
```

Lastly try wrapping the contents of URL with either back-ticks url('content'), I remember reading somewhere that when pumping CSS through a preprocessor (Wordpress/PHP) it is generally good practice to wrap your strings with back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Server Side Scripting in CSS file](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/2201.htm)s, this will you to access the Global Variables of your web server and dynamically match any server you're deploying to.

Please see [Server Side Scripting in CSS Files](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/2201.htm) for steps on implementing this.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but this is on a WordPress site.  I'm trying to manipulate an already created template.  WordPress seems to be changing the URL with however it processes the CSS files.

Comment: You can do this with WordPress, simply follow the instructions in the link I referenced, and in your WordPress themes header.php add in a stylesheet link to the css.php file and you'll be in business. Let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: It's a good idea in general, but in this example, it's much easier for me to just do a find and replace to make absolute paths in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I see it's not really answered.
As mentioned, it is not best practice to load theme related stuff from `wp-content/uploads/`.

But, if you really want to use something in `wp-content/uploads` you would use:

```
#topNav {background:#3a93c3 url("../../uploads/2011/07/blueNav.jpg") repeat-x;}
```

That path will work.

When calling a relative URL from theme php or css, the base url becomes `wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/` so you need to backup two directory levels (`../../`) to `wp-content/`.